# windows scheduler alternative for an asp.net webform application which is shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks, shared-hosting

Hai guys,
   Is there any alternative for windows scheduler for an asp.net application... The alernative must be capable of doing scheduled tasks as i am into shared hosting where i cant add any task scheduler to my server... I know there is quartz.net but my application needs only one task to be scheduled daily so i dont want to use it.... Any other alternative which can carry out scheduled tasks for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is..

You can **write a windows service** which will **call your application url** over a given period of time **recurrently**. Install and run this service from your personal computer or any other computer that you is mostly **[almost 24x7]** online.

Another way to this is..

use website uptime checking services. They call your URL at an interval. There are many free and paid services. I found **[this one](http://host-tracker.com/order-page/)** to be good enough after some googling.

**http://host-tracker.com/order-page/**

Comment: WHat happens if some others hit that page

Comment: which control panel are you using ?

Comment: You can add security tokens for this URL access. windows service can also act as cookie-enabled http-client and also store security cookies assigned by your url after authentication.

Comment: have the server check for the last time the task has been run; if less than 24 hours, then skip the action.  this would eliminate the need for security / authentication.

Comment: @jdigital: Not completely secure. If someone else executes the job then your authentic web-service will not be able to do the job. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Windows Service you could always just write a simple powershell script to execute at certain intervals, 3 lines of code.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
$ie.visible = $true
```

Comment: @bnkdev where should i keep this powershell script in my asp.net web application or i have to run it on my local system..